# Pipe output to command line editor for next command

Tags: command-line, terminal, vim, pipe

I have been using

```
sudo find / -iname '*foo*' 2>/dev/null | vim
```

to get a list of directories/files containing `foo`, and then I inspect this list, edit it, and write a bunch of new commands inside of vim.

After writing my commands inside of vim, I copy what I have written and quit vim then I paste it into the new command line.

Vim is my C-x C-e command line editor.

Can I make it so that `:wq` from inside of this vim session automatically fills the command line with the buffer?

As it would had I started vim with C-x C-e instead of `vim`.

How can I start a C-x C-e vim session with piped input?

Comment: To be clear, you want to open `vim`, and then in an empty buffer type `echo something` in that empty buffer and then you want to execute that buffer content? Then basically https://superuser.com/questions/266934/how-to-pass-vim-buffer-contents-through-shell-command-and-capture-the-output-to ?

Comment: @KamilCuk I want to write the buffer to the command line, not `:!` execute the command from within vim.

Comment: `I want to write the buffer to the command line` So like save to temporary file and then output that file? Along `.... | ( tmp=$(mktemp); trap 'rm "$tmp"' EXIT; cat > "$tmp"; vim "$tmp"; cat "$tmp"; )` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk you know if you press C-x C-e while you are at the command line, it opens up your configured text editor, so that you can edit the command line in your preferred environment. I want to start that C-x C-e session with buffer contents as provided by previous command's pipeline

Answer (score 5):

You could use `vipe` (from `moreutils`) as:

```
sudo find / -iname '*foo*' 2>/dev/null | vipe | "$SHELL"
```

Where `vipe` lets you edit the piped input and then feed it to your preferred shell.

Or:

```
sudo find / -iname '*foo*' 2>/dev/null | vipe | xclip -sel c
```

To save the edited pipe into the CLIPBOARD X11 selection.

`vipe` will launch the editor stored in `$VISUAL`, or `$EDITOR` if `$VISUAL` is not set or `vi` if neither is set.

If you want to push the result of that editing directly onto your shell's history, with `zsh`, that could be:

```
print -rs -- "$(sudo find / -iname '*foo*' 2>/dev/null | vipe)"
```

(and recall that with the <kbd>Up</kbd> key).

To put it directly into the shell's editing buffer, still with `zsh`, replace `print -rs` with `print -rz`.

Or if you don't have `vipe`:

```
(){vim $1 && print -rz -- "$(<$1)"} =(sudo find / -iname '*foo*' 2> /dev/null)
```

You could make a function for it like:

```
vif sudovif() {
  () {
    vim $1 &&
      print -rz -- "$(<$1)"
  } =(${0%vif} find "$@")
}
```

```
vif / -iname '*foo*'
```